# File reader skip empty line

Tags: angular, line, filereader

I am reading a file in my angular app through `FileReader`.
While reading I want to ignore the empty lines. My `file.txt` is:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I tried by using `linearray = this.myfilereader.result.split('\n');`. The length of `linearray` is 5, instead of 4.

How can we ignore empty line. I don't want to loop the linearray and check the length of each element and ignore.

Comment: Did you try \r\n?

Comment: that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer in the comments works for your current usecase, you might want to consider splitting on a regex instead:

```js
lineArray = this.myfilereader.result.split(/\r?\n/)
```

This way your code supports text files coming from both Windows and UNIX systems.